# How to combine all the elements of list to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

The following is a list with many many elements. Each elements is a dataframe. I want to combine all the dataframes to a dataframe.

```
[[1]]
     X1  X2  n
[1,] 13 156 12
[2,] 13 156 13
[3,] 13 156 14
[4,] 13 156 15

[[2]]
     X1  X2  n
[1,] 94 187 14
[2,] 94 187 15
[3,] 94 187 16

[[3]]
     X1  X2  n
[1,] 66 297 41
[2,] 66 297 42
[3,] 66 297 43
[4,] 66 297 44
[5,] 66 297 45
[6,] 66 297 46
[7,] 66 297 47
[8,] 66 297 48
     ...
     ...
```

How to combine all the elements of list to a dataframe which is as follows:

```
     X1  X2  n
[1,] 13 156 12
[2,] 13 156 13
[3,] 13 156 14
[4,] 13 156 15
[1,] 94 187 14
[2,] 94 187 15
[3,] 94 187 16
[1,] 66 297 41
[2,] 66 297 42
[3,] 66 297 43
[4,] 66 297 44
[5,] 66 297 45
[6,] 66 297 46
[7,] 66 297 47
[8,] 66 297 48
```

Comment: Those are matrices, not data.frames. looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily combine the data.frames with

```
do.call(rbind, mylist)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in base R as well, using function `do.call`. Below is the sample code.

```
dataList <- list()
dataList[[1]] <-  data.frame(x1=rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), n=1:10)
dataList[[2]] <-  data.frame(x1=rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), n=11:20)
dataList[[3]] <-  data.frame(x1=rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), n=21:30)

dataSet <- do.call(rbind, dataList)
```